# Как реализовать создание аккаунтов на поддомене?

Tags: vue.js, symfony

Имеем условно CMR систему:

1. Бэкенд - Symfony + Doctrine + MySQL
2. Фронтэнд - VueJS.
3. Хостинг виртуальный - beget.com

Задача - реализовать регистрацию пользователей с созданием поддомена для входа в CRM систему.
т.е. например основной домен у нас crm.ru.
Для пользователя создаем страницу входа например JohnDoe.crm.ru

Набросал пункты, как это может выглядеть:

1. Пользователь JohnDoe вводит на странице регистрации логин, пароль, email.
   => 2. Создаем поддомен, например JohnDoe.crm.ru. (Beget позволяет создать поддомен через API).
   => 3. Создаем новую (пустую) базу данных из резервной копии и как-то связываем с вновь зарегистрированным пользователем.
   => 4. Отправляем пользователю ссылку на созданный аккаунт JohnDoe.crm.ru.

Вопрос: На правильном ли я пути? Как обычно реализуется такая задача?

Comment: А не проще под пользователя создавать отдельную таблицу в базе - зачем множить поддомены? (пользователя не устроит ? ссылка типа crm.ru/pupkin)

Answer (score 0):

Symfony умеет в роутинг по поддоменам (https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#sub-domain-routing)

Т.е нужно

1. настроить переадресацию на веб-сервере `*.crm.ru` -> `crm.ru` (не забыть, видимо, исключить общеупотребимые, типа `www`, `smtp` и т.д.)
2. настроить роутинг для `{user}.crm.ru`
3. в коде искать полученного пользователя